# JSF keeps the old data

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces button that should process data via Java and display it in a dataTable.

This is the  code:

```
    <p:dataTable rowIndexVar="rowIndex" var="report" 
        id="TableResult" 
        style="height:685px;width: 97vw;" 
        value="#{reportResultController.resultRows}" 
        resizableColumns="true"
        scrollable="true"
        scrollHeight="95%"
        scrollRows="30"
        liveScroll="true"
        lazy="false"/>
```

and the button the renders the data of the table ():

```
           <p:commandButton value="Report "
                action="#{ReportController.produceReport}" id="produce_report"
                update="TableResult"
                process="TableResult"/>
```

This is the Java part

```
    public void produceReport() {
        resultRows = reportResultUtils.runReport(rph, rowsLimit); //Returning List of rows
}

    public List<Object[]> getResultRows() {
    return resultRows;
}
```

The process of the data is working just fine. 
The problem is that in a scenario which I press the button twice for the same data, for the first time I see the result and next time I see it double instead of one time.

**First time**

ID        NAME

1          David

2          Joe

**Second time**

ID   NAME

1    David

2    Joe

1    David

2    Joe

The third and fourth times are keeping it only double like the second time.

If I'm changing the parameters in order to get a different table so it clears the table and not mixing up the data.

What can I do in order to display it only one time or to delete the data in the table before setting new data in the resultRows var?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I edit the question

Comment: Are you implying that this problem doesn't occur when you invoke `reportResultUtils.runReport(rph, rowsLimit)` using a plain Java application class with a `main()` method instead of a whole JSF based user interface? Because, as far the question stands now, JSF is merely the model view presenter here and doesn't do have any influence on internal logics of `reportResultUtils.runReport(rph, rowsLimit)`. In other words, you would most likely have had exactly the same problem when presenting the model in another way, such as `System.out.println()` or even a whole different MVC framework.

Comment: Some other remarks: Tried disabling `liveScroll="true"` and what is your PF version? and `are you sure the `process="TableREsult"` on the button is correct?

Comment: @BalusC - I tried to add `System.out.println(resultRows.size())` inside the `getResultRows` and it printed the same correct size all the time. please see my answer below. Thank you both for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok

It turned out that it's a PrimeFace's [bug](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=44799).

Indeed as @Kukeltje mentioned, the problem is with the `liveScroll="true"`. 
When I remove it, it works.

So the workaround solution is to add `Rows` attribute to the DataTable with the same size as the `scrollRows`:

```
  <p:dataTable rowIndexVar="rowIndex" var="report" 
    id="TableResult" 
    style="height:685px;width: 97vw;" 
    value="#{reportResultController.resultRows}" 
    resizableColumns="true"
    scrollable="true"
    scrollHeight="95%"
    scrollRows="30"
    rows="30"  <!-- This is the solution-->
    liveScroll="true"
    lazy="false"/>
```

Comment: The link you refer to is about `lazy=true` and you have 'false'. And this is 'solved' in newer PF versions. What is yours?